# Open a view in UITabBarController

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitabbarcontroller

I need to open programatically a certain tab in my tab bar.

I tried calling the following method from my UITabBarController:

```
self.selectedViewController = myVController;
```

Which doesn't work.

What is the right way to open a tab?

Thank you.

Update: I tried the following code:

```
self.selectedViewController = [ [self viewControllers] objectAtIndex: 0];
```

which opens me a desirable tab(it is being selected), but the active view is not being updated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regarding the `selectedIndex` property, Apple's docs say:

> In versions of iPhone OS prior to
>   version 3.0, this property reflects
>   the index of the selected tab bar item
>   only. Attempting to set this value to
>   an index of a view controller that is
>   not visible in the tab bar, but is
>   instead managed by the More navigation
>   controller, has no effect.

Perhaps this was your problem?

One possible workaround is to use your own `UITabBar` and handle your own views. Then you can do something like this:

```
[tabBar setSelectedItem:[tabBar.items objectAtIndex:1]];
```

Just implement `UITabBarDelegate` and define this function to get item selection messages and manually switch views. (Although if you are using advanced `UITabBarController` features it may not be worth your effort.)

```
- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item
{

}
```

Answer (score -1):

The way I've done it is to use `self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 1` (first tab is at index 0).

Comment: It has the same problem that my code had. The view is not being always updated.